# Unable to find custom chaincode path Hyperledger Fabricv1.0 local network running on windows7

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to install my custom chain code in my local Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 environment.

For this I have followed the documentation [build your first network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) and I am using first network sample with in the [github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) project. No it is up and running with `./byfn.sh -m up` and executing all the scripts for channel creating, chain code installation and instantiation and all by running script.sh file.

Now I have changed the following to tryout my custom chaincode

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02>&log.txt
```

this I have changed to

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/myuserId/fabrcicV1_chaincodes/mychaincode >&log.txt
```

Now by running `./byfn.sh -m up` getting the exception

```
2017-08-22 11:01:17.048 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-22 11:01:17.048 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2017-08-22 11:01:17.048 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: path to chaincode does not exist: github.com/myuserId/fabrcicV1_chaincodes/mychaincode
Usage:
  peer chaincode install [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --ctor string      Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -l, --lang string      Language the chaincode is written in (default "golang")
  -n, --name string      Name of the chaincode
  -p, --path string      Path to chaincode
  -v, --version string   Version of the chaincode specified in install/instantiate/upgrade commands

Global Flags:
      --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoi
      --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
      --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
      --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode installation on remote peer PEER0 has Failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

I have the repository there in [github](https://github.com/), then why it is not showing **does not exit**?

I have *cloned* the same to **Windows 7** machine under the path $GOPATH/src/github.com/ and given local path, then also I am getting the same error. I am running all the commands through docker quick start terminal for **windows 7**.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Also in some of the network log I have found a location `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/....` and where it is pointing to. In my windows path gopath is `/c/users/public/fabricv1`.

Since I am not much familiar with the tool, please comment on this also.

> After doing some analysis from my side, it seems like the chain code
>   is reading from some pre-mounted directories ***sacc/, fabcar/, /marble02
>   , chaincode_example_02, hyperledger/*** under the path
>   ***`root@7785f8b27559:/opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev/chaincode#`*** and
>   chaincode also pre-loaded at the time of making the network up
>   using docker image. There it seems ***no effect by adding chaincode in
>   windows folder*** and it is from the above said virtual machine path.
>
> So what can I do now to continue my work? is there any way to install
>   my custom chaincode to the local network. I tried with my githhub path
>   and local path but no use. please somebody help :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you do not have your chaincode in the $GOPATH, you need to run:

```
go get github.com/myuserId/fabrcicV1_chaincodes/mychaincode
```

Before trying to install the chaincode on peer, in your case where you are using **build your first network**, you need to make sure your new chaincode inside `fabric-samples/chaincode` folder. And also note that you need to mount folder with your chaincode into docker cli container, see example of current `docker-compose-cli.yaml` file:

```
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
    - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
    - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
```

In particular, you probably need to replace here with your chaincode or make sure to mount an additional folder within `$GOPATH` of cli container:

```
- ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
```

Comment: Awesome !!..Since I am new to this configuration I missed it and after doing this step out everything is working fine. Big thanks :)